# Unused constructor instantiated in template class created by another constructor

Tags: c++, templates, void, sfinae, enable-if

I have the following class:

```cpp
template <typename T=void>
class Foo{
public:

  Foo(){};

  template <typename = typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<T>::value, std::nullptr_t>>
  Foo(const T&){};

};

int main() {
  Foo<void> v;
}
```

`v` is created using the first constructor. Therefore, there is no need to create the second constructor for `Foo<void>`.

Why does it get created anyways?

The problem is that explicitly creating the second constructor with the type `void` bypasses SFINAE, and tries to make a parameter of `const void&`. This is obviously not allowed.

How can I prevent the second constructor from being valid if `T` is `void`?

Answer (score 2):

> Why does it get created anyways?

Because in your template constructor

```
template <typename = typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<T>::value, std::nullptr_t>>
Foo(const T&){};
```

the value of the test for `std::enable_if` (`!std::is_void<T>::value`) depends from the template type of the class (`T`).

To SFINAE enable/disable a method of a class (or struct) you have to write a test that depends from a template parameter of the method itself.

A way to circumvent this problem is add a template parameter `U` for the method and give it `T` as default type. I mean something as

```
template <typename U = T,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<U>::value, std::nullptr_t>>
Foo(const U&){} // ..... the test depends from U ---^
//        ^--- U also here, to avoid the void reference problem
```

or, maybe better,

```
template <typename U = T, 
          std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<U>::value, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
Foo(const U&){}
```

Comment: That `U` is in a deduced context, allowing `Foo<void> v = 1`. You can put it in a non-deduced context and combine it with `enable_if` like: `template<typename U = T> Foo(const std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void_v<U>, U>&){}`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to disabling the constructor is to replace `const T&` with some unusable type when `T` is void:

```cpp
struct unusable {
  unusable() = delete;
  unusable(const unusable&) = delete;
  ~unusable() = delete;
};

template <typename T=void>
class Foo{
  using cref = std::conditional_t<std::is_void_v<T>, unusable, std::add_lvalue_reference_t<const T>>;
public:

  Foo(){}

  Foo(cref){}

};
```

This is useful `const T&` it is used in multiple places so you don't have to use SFINAE everywhere.